# Javascript focus() doesn't work in UIWebView if another element already had the focus

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, setfocus

I have encountered a Javascript problem in UIWebView:

I have two input elements on my webpage, say #focusone and #focustwo

```
<input type="text" id="focusone" size="35"></input><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="focustwo" size="35"></input>
```

In my script, I want to set the focus programmatically to #focusone.

```
function setFocus() {
  $("#focusone").focus();
}
```

(The problem appears with and without jQuery)

This works, as long as #focustwo didn't have the focus. If #focustwo (or any other element where the keyboard pops up) already had the focus, JavaScripts focus() method will set the focus to #focusone, but refuse to open the keyboard, or show the little vertical bar inside the input element which indicates that the input element actually has the focus. If no other element which opens the keyboard had the focus, everything works as intended.

The problem only appears in UIWebView - in Safari, everything works.

Has someone else experienced this problem and found any workarounds?

Comment: I have this exact problem. Did you end up finding a solution to it?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. I opened a ticket in the Apple bug reporter in August, but didn't get a response yet.